# make arrays accessible throughout methods and classes

Tags: java

how do i make an array accessible throughout classes and methods?
right now i have something similar to

```
public class Class
{
public int[] array = new int[value];
public static int var;
    public void callArray()
    {            
        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
            var++;
        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
        {
            value[x] = var;
            var = 0;
        }
    }

    public void anotherMethod()
    {
    int[] array = new int[var];
         for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
             System.out.println(array[x])
    }
}  
public class AnotherClass extends Class
{
int[] array = new int[var];
    for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
        System.out.println(array[x]);
}
```

and i get a null pointer or array out of bounds every time i do things like that
how can i make array available throughout multiple classes and methods?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `array` is a member of the class (*instance variable*) - you should use it, instead of creating a new *local variable*:

```
 int[] array = new int[value];
```

is creating a new local variable, and "working" on it, instead of working on the instance variable.

What you really need is:

```
public void callArray() {
    array = new int[value];
    //^^ note that we do not declare a new variable, and thus we use the instance variable

    for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
        //code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the array a field:

```
class MyClass {
    int[] array = new int[5];

    public void callArray()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
            //code
    }

    public void anotherMethod()
    {
         for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
             System.out.println(array[x])
    }
```

Comment: The array is already defined as an instance varaible - otherwise the behavior would not have been NPE or IndexOutOfBoundException - but a compilation error (in `anotherMethod()`)

Comment: I suspect the error was because array was never initialized: the only way I see an NPE happening is if array is null for array.length or array[0]

Answer (score 0):

If you need a process wide access to your array from many various class instances you may wrap it within [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class. If you need to access array within only one object where "callArray" and "anotherMethod" methods is implemented you can simply declare array as a class field:

```
public YourClass {
    private int[] array = new int[value];

    public void callArray()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
            //code
    }

    public void anotherMethod()
    {
       for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
          System.out.println(array[x])
    }
}
```